# How to use journal article model in my custom portlet in liferay 7 EE?

Tags: liferay

I want to use Journal article model in liferay 7 EE in my portlet. I am not able to import com.liferay.journal.model. I need help figuring out how to proceed..
or ways to use journal article model in custom portlet.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the build tool you're using. If you're using Liferay Workspace, you might miss the line

```
compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.journal.api", version: "2.1.0"
```

in your module's `build.gradle`